# Angular2 - Check if a div was changed by the server side

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following `div`:

```
<div *ngFor="let msg of hero.messages">
    <div>
        messageid: {{msg.messageid}} <br />
        messagetime: {{msg.messagetime}} <br />
        receivetime: {{msg.receivetime}}<br />
        positiontime: {{msg.positiontime}}<br />
        positionlatitude: {{msg.positionlatitude}}<br />
        positionlongitude: {{msg.positionlongitude}}<br />
        ls: {{msg.ls}}<br />
        parsed: {{msg.parsed}}<br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know when for example msg.messagetime changed. These are automatically changed every 5sec with a service call to the server. I tried with `ng-change="onChange(msg)"` but it is never fired. I would like to see when the value is changed in order to change its style for a few seconds.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: What do you mean "changed by the server"? If you have new data, it is fed into the hero.messages and your repeater will re-build the view and present the new values.

Comment: Do you mean ngOnChanges?

Comment: Yes exactly it does, but i would like to have a function that detects new changes of the values

Comment: Yes ngOnChanges but it never fired.. maybe i did it wrong